# Is my only option to check this integral for many values and attempt to find a pattern?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, partial-differential-equations

I have been attempting to solve the Laplace equation on a disk and am having trouble solving some of the related integrals.
For example, take the set up to be that $U(r,\theta) =\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\cos(2\theta)$.

Our solution comes in the form $$U(r,\theta)=a_0 +\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}r^m\left(a_m\cos(m\theta)+b_m \sin(m\theta)\right) $$

Now, straightforwardly one could just compare coefficients and see that $a_0 = 1/2, b_m=0,a_2=1/2$ and $a_m = 0$ for all other $m \in \mathbb{N}$. But I would like to compute the coefficients by using the integral formulas. It is very easy to determine $a_0$ so I will ask we focus on solving for $a_m$.
The formula for $a_m$ is:
$$a_m = \frac{1}{\pi r^m} \int_0^{2\pi} \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \cos(2\theta)\right) \cos(m\theta)d\theta $$

Evaluating this, one finds that $$a_m = - \frac{1}{\pi r^m} \dfrac{2\sin\left(2{\pi}m\right)}{m\cdot\left(m^2-4\right)} $$

Which is identically $0$ for all $m$ apart from $m=2$, and then it is undefined and I would have to calculate the above integral by substituting $2$ in for $m$. Is this my only option for solving this type of problem? As my title suggests, I feel like it would be faster to calculate $a_m$ via the integral for many values of $m$ and seeing if a pattern emerges.

Comment: The integral formulas are based on the fact that $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(nx)\cos(mx)\,dx = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(nx)\sin(mx)\,dx = 0$$ for $m \neq n$ and $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(nx)^2\,dx = 1/2$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out to me. This was never brought to my attention before.